# ASP.NET Core Interception with Castle.DinamicProxy doesn't throw Exception with Async Methods !!! How can I solve this?

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, aop

I have been creating a project with Aspect Oriented Programming paradigm and

I have an "**ExceptionLogAspect**" class attribute which is used on business methods to log the errors throwing from them.

```
 public class ExceptionLogAspect : MethodInterception
{
    private readonly LoggerServiceBase _loggerServiceBase;
    private static byte _risk;

    public ExceptionLogAspect(Type loggerService, byte risk)
    {
        if (loggerService.BaseType != typeof(LoggerServiceBase))
        {
            throw new System.Exception(AspectMessages.WrongLoggerType);
        }

        _loggerServiceBase = (LoggerServiceBase)Activator.CreateInstance(loggerService);
        _risk = risk;
    }

    protected override void OnException(IInvocation invocation, System.Exception e)
    {
        var logDetailWithException = GetLogDetail(invocation);
        logDetailWithException.ExceptionMessage = e.Message;
        _loggerServiceBase.Error(logDetailWithException);
    }
}
```

This Aspect migrates **MethodInterception** class that I created with Castle.DinamicProxy package. And **OnException** method included by **MethodInterception** logs the exception data.

```
 public abstract class MethodInterception:MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute
{
    protected virtual void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation){}
    protected virtual void OnAfter(IInvocation invocation){}
    protected virtual void OnException(IInvocation invocation, System.Exception e){}
    protected virtual void OnSuccess(IInvocation invocation){}
    public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var isSuccess = true;

        OnBefore(invocation);
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();//Business Method works here.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            isSuccess = false;
            OnException(invocation, e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(isSuccess)
                OnSuccess(invocation);
        }
        OnAfter(invocation);
    }
}
```

When I run the code and try-catch block doesn't work for Exception. So catch block isn't called and no messages are logged.

If I turn the business method into a syncronous method, exception will be thrown and data will be logged.

How can I solve this asynchronous method problem?

Comment: Not sure about the solution, but it might be good to understand why that happens. An async method doesn't throw an exception, it returns a faulted Task. When you await a faulted Task, the code generated by the compiler throws an exception when checking the Task status.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this solution, it works properly.**

Intercept method has to be like this to make this process asynchronous.

Otherwise, this method doesn't work properly for async.

There are some other ways, for example Castle CoreAsync Interceptor, you can find it on Github or NuGet.

https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor

```
    public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var isSuccess = true;

        OnBefore(invocation);
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed(); //Metodu çalıştır
            
            if (invocation.ReturnValue is Task returnValueTask)
            {
                returnValueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            if (invocation.ReturnValue is Task task && task.Exception != null)
            {
                throw task.Exception;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            isSuccess = false;
            OnException(invocation, e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isSuccess)
                OnSuccess(invocation);
        }
        OnAfter(invocation);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).